# Scroll inside div with jquery?

Tags: jquery, scroll, overflow

If I have a div that is overflowing, is there a way I could call a jquery function to scroll it down 60px or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use [ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin.

**UPDATE**
Seems like link is broken now. New link [here](http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

Answer (score 5):

Or, simply use the [scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) jQuery API call.

Answer (score 3):

mine is going like this:

```
            var offset = item.position().top;
            if (offset < 0 || offset > parent.height()) {
                if (offset < 0)
                    offset = parent.scrollTop() + offset;
                parent.animate({ scrollTop: offset }, 300);
            }
```